# I need to add footer with some design in every pdf page in Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am converting html to pdf by using `jspdf` and `html2canvas` in Angular 10. But `addHtml` and `fromHtml` are not working.
How can I add footer with some design for every page?

This is my code.

```js
var data = document.getElementById('contentToConvert');
html2canvas(data).then((canvas) => {
  var imgWidth = 208;
  var pageHeight = 295;
  var imgHeight = (canvas.height * imgWidth) / canvas.width;
  var heightLeft = imgHeight;

  const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

  let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4');
  var position = 0;
  pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
  heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  while (heightLeft >= 0) {
    position = heightLeft - imgHeight - 2;
    pdf.addPage();
    pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight);
    heightLeft -= pageHeight;
  }
  pdf.save('report.pdf');
});
```

Comment: What does footer on every page have to do with PDF?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? it's `jsPDF` or `jspdf ` ?

Comment: Actually, we need to add a specific footer with some design. I am able to add Page 1, Page 2 Page 3 ... in pdf , but need to add some  specific design in pdf.

Comment: I have tried addHtml and fromHtml  but it says  fromHtml is not a function and same for addHtml.